Calculate the $p$-adic absolute value of $\frac{1}{p^7-p^5+p^3}$
I want to solve the following exercise:
Calculate the $p$-adic absolute value of
$\frac{1}{p^7-p^5+p^3}$.
My Approach:
For the $p$-adic absolute value, we have the following rules:
$|xy|_p=|x|_p |y|_p$
And if $|x|_p \neq |y|_p$ then $|x+y|_p =max(|x|_p,|y|_p)$.
$(*)$ Thus we get $|\frac{1}{p^7-p^5+p^3}|_p=\frac{|1|_p}{|p^7-p^5+p^3|_p}$
Next step is to calculate $|p^7|_p, |-p^5|_p, |p^3|_p$.
We know that for $x \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ the p-adic absolute value is defined as $|x|_p=p^{- \nu_p(x)}$, where $\nu_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation.
$\nu_p$ maps $\mathbb{Q}_p$ to $\mathbb{Z} \cup \{\infty\} $with $p^mu \mapsto m$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}, u \in \mathbb{Z}_p$.
Thus, in our case:
$\nu_p(p^7)=7$
$\nu_p(-p^5)=\nu_p(-1 \cdot p^5)=5$
$\nu_p(p^3)=3$
Now we see that $\max(|p^7|_p,|-p^5|_p,|p^3|_p)=|p^3|=p^{-3}$.
Continuing the calculation from $(*)$ we get
$\frac{|1|_p}{|p^7-p^5+p^3|_p} =\frac{|1|_p}{p^{-3}}=|1|_p p^3$.
Calculating
$\nu_p(1)=\nu_p(p^0 \cdot 1)=0$, thus $|1|_p=1$ and so $|\frac{1}{p^7-p^5+p^3}|_p=p^3$.
Now, I tried to look at the solutions/hints for this exercise. There only was the following hint $p^7-p^5+p^3=p^3 \cdot u$ for a unit $u$.
My Questions are the following:
Is my solution/calculation correct?
I am a little bit confused by the hint. Why is $p^7-p^5+p^3=p^3 \cdot u$? How would one use the hint to solve this exercise?
Would one still calculate it, like I did, or is there another way to do it? (Being able to replace $p^7-p^5+p^3$ with $p^3 \cdot u$ looks like a shortcut to me, but I am unsure if there is more to it.)

It looks a bit excessive but not wrong. One important detail I would mention is that $|x+y|_p=\max(|x|_p,|y|_p)$ is only guaranteed by the ultrametric inequality's strong property when $|x|_p\ne |y|_p$, since you compute it via the max of the 3 absolute values which is not generally a true statement.

@J.W.Tanner Sorry that should have been $\mathbb{Z}$. Just a typo

$p^7 - p^5 + p^3 = (p^4 - p^2 + 1) \cdot p^3$, so $u = p^4 - p^2 + 1$.  This is a unit (in the ring $\mathbb Z_p$ of $p$-adic integers) because $\nu_p(u) = 0$.  Then $|p^7 - p^5 + p^3|_p = |u|_p |p^3|_p = p^{-3}$ and
$|1/(p^7 - p^5 + p^3)|_p = 1/|p^7 - p^5 + p^3|_p = p^3$.

Thank you very much!
